# Should I use const on a variable with different assignments in different function calls but that is not reassigned in the same call

Tags: node.js, variables, constants, variable-declaration

Let's say I have a variable which gets a request from a database, the request is going to be different every time the function is being called, but within one run of the function, that variable is not going to reassigned. Should I use LET or CONST please? It's quite confusing

```js
async setSetting(guildID, settingName, value) {
  let settingToFind = { guildID: guildID, setting: settingName };
  /* Some code but settingToFind is not reassigned within the function... */
}
```

Here is an other example of where I'm not sure if I should use let or const (for settingToFind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `const`! This will remind other devs or your self in the future to not reassign this var or at least to think about it. If you want to allow to change it later on you could use `let`, but it's common to put as strict as possible in first palce.

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question:

> but within one run of the function, that variable is not going to reassigned

You should use `const`

Comment: Thanks, that what I was looking for

Comment: Great to hear it @jojos38 - would you mind pressing the tick next to my answer to indicate that it resolves your query?

Comment: I need to wait 10 minutes